# Django: How to enable app usage for different societies

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a django project that has many apps.
There is a core app that has all the main models that other secondary apps will use.

One model in the core app is called SocietyEntity:

```
class SocietyEntity(models.Model):
id              = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
referenceName   = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Nombre")
members         = models.ManyToManyField(get_user_model())
administrator   = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Administrator")
```

As shown, the societies can have one o more users as members. What I want to achieve is some kind of relation between societies and the other secondary apps of the project, that enable that society to make use of the app.
Something like a manytomany kind of relation between SocietyEntity and app names?
I'm not sure but I think I need some way to relate societies to apps, if that is even possible.

If a society doesn't have permission to use an app, this shouldn't be listed in the admin interface for example.

Any suggestion is well received! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create relationships among models from different apps. Just import the model you want from your desired app into the app you want to use it in. For example, if you have another app called `community` with a model `Resort`, you can create a relationship with `SocietyEntity` from `core` app:

```
from core.models import SocietyEntity


class Resort(models.Model):
    society_entity = models.ForeignKey(SocietyEntity, ....)
```

But when importing models to use in model relationships, beware that you may run into a `circular import` error if you each models.py is importing from each other:

**community/models.py**

```
from core.models import SocietyEntity
```

**core/models.py**

```
from community.models import Resort
```

To avoid this, Django lets you define relationship with a model from another app without explicitly importing it, like so:

```
class Resort(models.Model):
    society_entity = models.ForeignKey("core.SocietyEntity", ....)
    ...
```

This way is safe, even when apps are using models from each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't have anything to do with the question asked.